# Javascript: for loop gets data but the order is ruined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, loops

I have a function where I am using a for loop to grab pages through an ajax request. It all works fine except that often the pages are in the wrong order. I think this is probably because of the async function inside of the loop, but I do not know how to fix it. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
$http.get(link).
        success(function (data) {               
            var num = parseInt($(data).find('.r.m .l').first().text().split(' ').pop());
            var total = num + 1;                

            var pages = [];
            var query = removeLastPart(link);

            for (var i = page; i < total; i++) {
                var full = query + "/" + i + ".html";
                $http.get(full).
                success(function (data) {                       
                    pages.push({image: $(data).find('img#image').attr('src')});
                    j++;
                    if (i == total) {                           
                        cb(pages);
                    }
                }).
                error(function () {
                    console.log("Error getting chapter");
                });
            }

        }).
        error(function () {
            console.log("Error getting page number");
        });
```

Comment: Don't push into the `pages` array. You already know how many pages are going to come in. Just assign the correct page to the correct index. `pages[i] = {image:...` instead of `pages.push()` EDIT: See @Patrick Evans's answer.

Comment: You also need to pass 2 arguments to `parseInt`: the value to parse and the  `radix`.  Without the radix, it will try to guess what base you meant by the text!  `parseInt("0x10")` becomes `16` because i thinks hex instead of `10` / error.  Older browsers will sometimes do octal too!.  Always add the base 10.

Comment: In regards to my previous comment, you should use a tool like jshint to catch these common javascript problems to save you future headaches.  IIRC, it will also catch the scoping issues that Patrick Evans talks about (fixed by using an IIFE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct due to the async calls your requests will possibly be done out of order. You can combat this by either using an IIFE or by moving your ajax call to a separate function and pass the index the page should be loaded to.

IIFE

```
for (var i = page; i < total; i++) {
    var full = query + "/" + i + ".html";
    (function(idx){
       $http.get(full).
           success(function (data) {                       
               pages[idx] = {image: $(data).find('img#image').attr('src')};
               j++;
               //assuming j is a counter for knowing when pages are loaded
               if (j == total) {                           
                   cb(pages);
               }
           }).
           error(function () {
              console.log("Error getting chapter");
           });
    })(i);
}
```

Separate function call

```
function doAjax(url,pageArray,idx,cb){
    $http.get(url).
       success(function (data) {                       
           pageArray[idx] = {image: $(data).find('img#image').attr('src')};
           j++;
           //assuming j is a counter for knowing when pages are loaded
           if (j == total) {                           
               cb(pages);
           }
       }).
       error(function () {
           console.log("Error getting chapter");
       });
}

//....
for (var i = page; i < total; i++) {
    var full = query + "/" + i + ".html";
    doAjax(full,pages,i,cb);
 }
```

Note since $http calls return a promise you can use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to wait till all the pages are loaded to call your `cb(pages)` call instead of incrementing j and checking (I am assuming that is what your if statement for the cb(pages) is attempting to accomplish)

```
function doAjax(url,pageArray,idx){
    return $http.get(url).
       success(function (data) {                       
           pageArray[idx] = {image: $(data).find('img#image').attr('src')};
       }).
       error(function () {
           console.log("Error getting chapter");
       });
}

//....
var ajaxCalls = [];
for (var i = page; i < total; i++) {
    var full = query + "/" + i + ".html";
    ajaxCalls.push( doAjax(full,pages,i) );
 }
 $q.all(ajaxCalls).then(function(){
    cb(pages);
 });
```

Comment: If we are going to use $q.all, we probably want to modify it's result directly instead of manually insterting the results one by one into pageArray.  Then we don't even have to worry about passing the index/array around and the code is clearer.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpmd91uz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax by its definition is asynchronous so you can't assure the order things will return in. What you could do is after you have the enter data set back you could sort the array yourself.

Comment: The order of response will not be same as the sorted data!

Comment: @RahulB If it was, he wouldn't need to sort to begin with.

Comment: @PatrickMotard : The OP doesn't want a sorted response. The response should be available in order of request! Sorting the response after all ajax call are done will not bring the array in the order of request, it will arrange data in the order of value! This solution is not correct

Comment: He didn't say how he was going to sort it. Since he knew that his data was not in order it was implied that OP knew which order he wanted them in, thus he can sort them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use $q.all, the results will be returned in the same order they were called regardless of which one actually returns first.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q